# telebot - создание рейтинга сообщений

Tags: python, telebot

Доброго времени суток.

Есть задача: нужно дать пользователю возможность оценить сообщение:

- *+1 к рейтингу*
- *0 к рейтингу*
- *-1 к рейтингу*

Вопрос состоит в том, как это можно реализовать?
python3, pytelegrambotapi

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем ясно о каком сообщении идет речь. Отправленное кем и куда?
Если речь о сообщении которое пользователь оставляет в группе в которой бот админ и может читать сообщения, то после получения отправляем в группу сообщение с именем пользователя и его же текстом, и приделываем три инлайн кнопки или сколько нужно. Изначальное сообщение пользователя удаляем чтобы не дублировалось.
В callback data кнопок храним id сообщения и собственно оценку.
В хэндлере кнопок обрабатываем уже как нужно. Можно сохранять рейтинг в БД, можно редактировать сообщение и указывать в нём же его рейтинг. Зависит от конечной цели.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать базу данных из репутацией, и когдаа кто-то хочет поставить репутацию, данные в базе данных обновляются на новые, могу посоветовать SQL, надеюсь этот ответ поможет вам =)